# I have a problem duplicating a Mesh and again applying curve modifiers to the copy correctly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, error

I have a cube (A1) and a nurbs curve (N1)
I use an array modifier and a curve modifier so that cube (A1) follows the curve (N1) and fills exactly. But I do not apply the modifiers.

I then use SHIFT+D to copy A1, which gives me a new cube mesh, A2. I make a new nurbs curve, N2. I cannot use this new cube, A2 on the new nurbs curve because when I get upto the step of using a curve modifier, A2 just goes all over the place or stretches too big. Why and how and can this be fixed?

I've tried applying rotation, scale and location on everything, tried changing all the modifier settings  and tried multiple times in different ways but cannot get it to work.

I've tried this both on blender 2.74 and blender 2.79 and it's the same thing.

recreated blend file: [image]

Comment: Can you add a sample file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure. I have uploaded my blend file  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6174" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6174/)

Comment: moonboots I think I understand, I just tried it. I have to duplicate both A1 and N1 then delete the duplicate nurbs curve, and I can use the new duplicate cube for another curve! However there is a new problem, on my original project turns out I have already deleted the curve so the original mesh cannot be deleted/unlinked from it?

Comment: that's just so I can move mesh around the curve as I need. But there might be another way to do that. I'm just beginner so I'm not really sure what it does, just that's how I use in past. Also, how on earth did you figure out I needed to duplicate both Nurbscurve and mesh? Is there a book somewhere covering the bugs? lol how do I see how many times I've scaled curve?

Comment: you've enabled the Object Offset of the Array modifier, is there a reason for that? Because it messes your object: your curve is scaled 6 times, so it will also scale your cube 6 times... and if you choose to apply the scale of your curve, don't forget to bring back the Radius of your curve vertices to 1 in Edit mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've enabled the *Object Offset* of the *Array* modifier, with your curve as the offset object, is there a reason for that? Because it messes your object: as your curve is scaled 6 times, it will also scale your cube 6 times...

*Object Offset* will array your object taking account of the location, rotation and scale of the chosen object, like for example it will scale your original object increasingly if your offset object has been scaled, which is not what you want, you want a simple array, then a second modifier that makes the array follow a curve.

So disable this option as you just want your cube to be duplicated. It's the next modifier (*Curve*) that will take care of making your object following the curve.

Also, if you choose to apply the scale of your curve, don't forget, in *Edit* mode, to bring back the *Radius* of your curve vertices to 1 (on the *N* panel of your 3D view).